# Getting all coordinates from a line drawn on a map

Tags: android, google-maps, openstreetmap

in my `MapView` I give the ability to tap on the map to create as many points as you want and the points get connected by a line but I dont want to draw any lines that may intersect with another line on the map like this

[image]

Is there anyway to get the coordinates of the lines to check if the new line will intersect with one of the others?

Or if anyone else has any suggestion on how to check for this that would be great too

this is my draw method that draws the lines

```
@Override
    public void draw(final Canvas canvas, final MapView mapView, final boolean shadow){
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        try{
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        paint.setAlpha(100);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

        Path path = new Path();
        Point point1 = null;
        boolean runOnce = false;
        for(int i = 0;i<items.size();i++){
            Point point = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(items.get(i).mGeoPoint, point);

            if(!runOnce)
            {
                path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
                point1 = new Point(point.x, point.y);
                runOnce = true;
            }
            else
            {
                path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
            }
        }
        path.lineTo(point1.x, point1.y);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        path.lineTo(point1.x, point1.y);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        Paint paint2 = new Paint();
        paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint2.setDither(true);
        paint2.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint2.setStrokeWidth(3);
        paint2.setAlpha(20);
        paint2.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        Path path2 = new Path();
        Point point2 = null;
        boolean runOnce2 = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
            Point point = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(items.get(i).mGeoPoint, point);

            if(!runOnce2)
            {
                path2.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
                point2 = new Point(point.x, point.y);
                runOnce2 = true;
            }
            else
            {
                path2.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
            }
        }

        path2.lineTo(point2.x, point2.y);
        canvas.drawPath(path2, paint2);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
```

Comment: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/lineline2d/

Comment: that wont work because it is going to consider connecting end points as intersecting

Comment: You were basically asking how to calculate the intersection point between two line segments. The end points are of course part of the line segments. And this can be easily solved with mathematics. If you do not want that your end points count as intersection, then just check first whether your end points overlap. That can be solved using an if statement like the following: if(Math.abs(x1 - x2) < EPSILON && Math.abs(y1 - y2) < EPSILON) where EPSILON is your error tolerance value, something like 0.001 for example.

Comment: got it thanks!! if you submit an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go :-)

[paulbourke.net/geometry/lineline2d](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/lineline2d/)

Tells you how to mathematically determine the intersection point of two line segments.

If you do not want that your end points count as intersection, then just check first whether your end points overlap. That can be solved using an if statement like the following:

```
if(Math.abs(x1 - x2) < EPSILON && Math.abs(y1 - y2) < EPSILON)
```

where EPSILON is your error tolerance value, something like 0.001 for example.